# Site Refused to connect while PDF document reading in Embed Tag an other website

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, pdf, embedded, x-frame

I am using SharePoint 2013 and I am facing the issue to display the PDF Document in embed tag.

**Error Showing**:

1. SharePoint Site Refused Connect in Embed.
2. Refused to display 'http://SITE/HR/EmployeeDoc/Passport.pdf' in a frame because it set multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values ('SAMEORIGIN, Allow-From'). Falling back to 'deny'. IN Console Log.

**Note** :

it was continuously working from last 3 year perfectly and **i am getting this Error only from 3 Days**.

I did not change anything from last 5 months inside the process, inside the SharePoint Master Page OR any permission.

Only PDF Document not displaying, Images showing perfectly. and if i am accessing the PDF URL Direct in address bar than there is no issue at all.

can any buddy suggest me why it's refusing and please provide the solution.

Kindly Please help me to solve this issue.

Thank You.

Comment: We are also experiencing this issue using SharePoint Online. Same scenarios and error 1, and it has also been working fine for several months. We believe it relates to a Google Chrome update (currently on version 77.0.3865.90) as the same webpage with embed tag works fine in IE. So unfortunately we are still looking for a solution as well.